# How to sum hours in bracket with many bracket in one text string in EXCEL?

Tags: excel

[image]

Hi all

I have a table like this in excel with example two instructor (Wong and Veronica)

The number in bracket let's say (9-18) is the timing which mean instructor work from 0900-1800HRS

Sometimes I have more than 1 timing because instructor do double class let's say from (9-13) then (14-18)

How can each cell, the class hour be calculated with the sum of brackets?

Comment: Please, post what you have tried until now.

Comment: I dont know how to start with ...